# What is the fastest way to check if a string contains only white spaces in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can use regex in order to check if a string contains only white spaces, so my function could be

```
/^\s+$/.test(myString);
```

I could also use:

```
0 === myString.trim().length
```

or

```
var spaces = [" ", "\f", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\v", "\u00A0", "\u2028", "\u2029"];
for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    if (spaces.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) < 0) return false;
}
return true;
```

I tested them with an array with 10K strings (5K was only whitespaces) with max 100 characters and I got these results:

First test: 
Regex method: 35msec
Trim method: 6msec
Comparison method: 29msec

Second test (so maybe with some sort of cache):
Regex method: 6msec
Trim method: 7msec
Comparison method: 30msec

But I don't know if there are other ways and what is effectively the best method in terms of speed.

Comment: Are you going to process so much strings? If not, then I don't think there is any real difference.

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimisation. Go with the `trim()` method, you actually run in to a performance issue.

Comment: @fcalderan that will only work for empty strings

Comment: Go with the trim method, it's the most suitable one.

Comment: This question is just out of curiosity, in my case I have less than 10K strings (but they could be long strings) so there is no real difference but I'd like to know what is the best method if I should process billions of strings.

Comment: Go with`trim` ... everybody immediately gets the point and important too, you really don't want to handle all the possible whitespaces by yourself ... https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-white-space, http://xahlee.info/js/js_whitespace.html ... `trim` is optimized for that.

Comment: Yeah, I'd never use the third method, it was just for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are compiled into a finite state automaton which (for truly regular expressions, like yours) are pretty well optimized and guarantee a linear complexity.

The compilation can take time, which would explain your initial longer time. Any subsequent use of the regex won't need to do that again.

`trim` is probably also well optimized. It makes sense that both would have similar performance. The third option is clearly more complex.